# Detect Alt/Option + another key in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, macos, textarea, onkeydown

I want to detect when the Alt/Option key and any other key are both pressed down simultaneously in a textarea on Mac. For example, I want to check for Alt/Option + 'h':

**HTML**

```
<textarea onkeydown="myFunction(event);"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.key=="h") {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

The function works if I use Control instead of Alt. How can I get this to work with Alt on Mac?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdt02kgq/)

Comment: Add you code to **JSFiddle** so anyone can try directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by directly ASCII value `e.keyCode === 65` instead of checking by `e.key == 'A'`

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    if ( e.altKey && e.keyCode === 65) //it check both  altKey + 'A' or 'a' 
  {
    //do something 
  }
}
```

i just did this for **alt + a** press. but you can do with any key by getting  it's [ASCII](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) values
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devanghingu/wjvx8qap/20/) link for demo